# Xpath wildcard in Selenium to capture multiple instances of results

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying gather some data from a site using Python, Selenium and Xpath.  There are multiple datapoints I want and they are all in this structure:

```
/tr[1]/td
/tr[2]/td
/tr[3]/td
/tr[4]/td
```

I do not know how many `<tr>`'s there are so I am trying to search in a way that just gives me all results (hopefully in a list). How do I do that?

Here is my actual code but this is only giving me individual results. I'm new to web scraping and unsure if the issue is with my Xpath (not doing wildcards correctly or if its related to my get_attribute tag - if its getting innerhtml then is it only getting it for the single entry?)

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-stockFinancials_tabs"]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td').get_attribute("innerHTML")
print data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give `find_elements_by_xpath` a try.

I think, without seeing your full HTML, that this would work:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-stockFinancials_tabs"]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td')
for element in data:
    print element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: omg thank you! I didn't realize there was a find_elementS.  It works like a charm! Thank you so much.